# Cannot able to access API in on-premise

Tags: tyk

I have installed Tyk( dashboard, gateway & pump) as a docker image on our local machine.

We have created API by ( System Management -> APIs -> Add New API) with below-mentioned configuration via Tyk Dashboard UI.

API-Name: My API
Listen Path: /test-api/
Target URL: http://httpbin.org/

Now the problem is that I am getting "Not Found" error when we access the API.

Could someone help me to resolve this issue?

Request: curl -X GET http://api-dashboard:3000/test-api/get -v
Response: 404 (Not Found)

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api-dashboard (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /test-api/get HTTP/1.1
> Host: api-dashboard:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, private
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2019 08:58:35 GMT
< Content-Length: 9
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
<
* Connection #0 to host api-dashboard left intact
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the dashboard, you should be calling your gateway url instead.
E.g. http://api-gateway:8080/test-api/get

Tyk gateway default port is 8080.